# Drag & Drop with nested target in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, nested, drag-and-drop

I'm using HTML5 drag&drop; I have a droppable div and inside it I have another droppable div.

```
<div id="target-parent">
    <div id="target-child"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that if I drag something into the target-child, fire his drop event (and this is right) but in the end fire also the target-parent event.
How can the code understand that the dropped element is only target-child?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your event handler examine the `event.target` and behave appropriately and/or [call `event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation).

Comment: It's perfect with event.stopPropagation() :) Thank you!!